# OAuth 2.0 Tutorial?

Tags: python, oauth

I'm writing a REST web service on twisted and I want to use OAuth **2.0** for authorization. Is there a tutorial out there to help me write the OAuth server without having to read the entire spec? I know it's in draft, but even Facebook is using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth ends up being so simple, there's really no need for a library. It boils down to using HTTPS and passing the correct POST parameters as specified in the draft: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-10

Comment: Anyone who writes 2.0 does not require a client library gets my +1.

Comment: He specifically is asking about tutorials, not libraries. An IETF spec is not a tutorial.

Comment: @nailer I am the op as well as the answerer in this case...

Comment: @MattWilliamson Sure, but questions on SO aren't just for the OP. Plenty of people reading this want an actual tutorial as your question asked for: I know I did.

Answer (score 11):

**Edit for 2012**: Try Google OAuth 2 playground at https://code.google.com/oauthplayground for a practical demo. It will allow you to see working requests.

There aren't any good, generic OAuth 2 tutorials. Obviously the IETF spec, like any engineering spec, is designed to be specific and verbose rather than short and simple.

Additionally many other oAuth 2 documents are diffs of oAuth 1, which is a horrible way to try and learn something.

I find Google's own (Google-specific) oAuth 2 documents relatively good to get an understanding of how it practically works - what's sent, in what request, to whom:
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: The link is down to the playground is down. It's probably this: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: Thanks @TedKleinBergman. Updated.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I have an example project here using django and piston with oauth2: https://bitbucket.org/justinfx/django-piston-oauth2-nonrel-example

Comment: as jdl says in the link, the example is oauth 1.0, not 2.0.