# is it possible to create an app & get access token in dropbox using python code

Tags: python, python-2.7, dropbox, dropbox-api

I picked dropbox today. Please assist keeping that in mind.
I need to write a code which will create dropbox develop app. From there need to retrieve key & secret value. useing that need to retrieve access token.

Is there any way to do in code. If not, please suggest me any recursive way to do it.

So you may assist me, how to get access token from key & secret without going to web browser

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [their docs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/python), dropbox uses OAuth2. Have a look @ their sdk/api or some OAuth2 examples and [libraries](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) in python. For that, google is your friend.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480519/oauth-2-0-tutorial) has some links which may be of some help.